# '$a$' for which $f(x)=\left(\frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a}-1\right)x^5-3x+\log 5$ is decreasing for all $x\in\mathcal{R}$

Tags: derivatives

> Set of all values of '$a$' for which $f(x)=\bigg(\dfrac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a}-1\bigg)x^5-3x+\log 5$ decreases for all real $x$

$$
a\neq1\;\&\; a\geq -4\\
f'(x)=5\bigg(\dfrac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a}-1\bigg)x^4-3<0\\
\bigg(\dfrac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a}-1\bigg)x^4<\frac{3}{5}\text{ for all} x\in\mathcal{R}\\
\dfrac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a}-1=0\implies\sqrt{a+4}=1-a\\
a+4=1+a^2-2a\implies a^2-3a-3=0\implies a=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{21}}{2}
$$

My reference gives the solution $a\in\big[-4,\dfrac{3-\sqrt{21}}{2}\big]\cup(1,\infty)$, yet I am stuck here. Could anyone give a hint of whats the way forward ?

Comment: Minor correction: you should have

$$\frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a} \cdot x^4 < \frac 3 5$$

on your last line.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer thanks. stupid typo.

Comment: The solution is wrong. If $a<1$, then $f'(x)>0$ for $x$ large enough.

Comment: $a > 1$ obviously satisfies because $\frac{\sqrt{a + 4}}{1-a} x^4 < 0 < \frac{3}{5}.$ . Another case: $a=-4$ implies $f(x) = const$, however for $a \in (-4, \frac{3 - \sqrt{21}}{2}]$ function will not be decreasing (it is clear from your latest inequality, because $x^4$ is not bounded

Comment: @govordovsky Nice catch. I forgot $a=-4$. So the set is $\{-4\}\cup(1, +\infty)$

Comment: @govordovsky is there a proper way to arrive the range of $a$ ?

Comment: @Gribouillis how do we derive it in the first place ?

Comment: @Gribouillis Kindly check OP, I have edited a small correction

Comment: So it amounts now to solving $\frac{\sqrt{4+a}}{1-a} - 1 \le 0$

Comment: @Gribouillis yes. Thats whr I am stuck.

Comment: If $a\gt 1$, then $\frac{\sqrt{4+a}}{1-a}-1\lt 0$. If $a\lt 1$, then $\frac{\sqrt{4+a}}{1-a}-1\le 0\iff \sqrt{4+a}\le 1-a\iff 4+a\le (1-a)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=k x^5 -3x + \log 5 \implies y'=5kx^4 -3$ if $y(x)$ is increasing for all real values of $x$, then $y'=5kx^4 \le 3 \implies \frac{6k}{3} x^4 \le 0\implies k \le 0
.$
$$\implies \frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a} \le 1 \implies a\ge -4.~~~ (1)$$
Additionally, two cases arise here:

Case 1: when $a < 1$: squaring (1), we get $a^2-3a-3 \ge 0 \implies 
 a \in[-4, \frac{3-\sqrt{21}}{2}].$

Case 2: $a \in (1, \infty)$, then $\sqrt{a+4} \ge 1-a$, is true.

Finally, $a \in [-4,\frac{3-\sqrt{21}}{2}] \cup (1,\infty)$

Comment: Please check OP. there was a mistake, its is not $\dfrac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a}$ rather $\dfrac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a}-1$

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

reference gives wrong solution (e.g. try $a=-3$ and check the chart).

You had the right idea about checking the derivative.
$f$ is differentiable, thus $f$ is decreasing equivalent to $f'(x) < 0$, which implies inequality you had:

$$\frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a}x^4 < \frac{3}{5}$$

now notice that if $\frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a}$ is positive, then for all $ x > (\frac{3}{5} \frac{1-a}{\sqrt{a+4}})^{\frac{1}{4}}$, inequality will not hold, thus we should be looking only for those $a$, for which $\frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a} \le 0.$

if $\frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a} = 0$, then condition holds and that gives you $a=-4$.

if $\frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a} < 0$, then $\frac{\sqrt{a+4}}{1-a}x^4 < 0 < \frac{3}{5}$ - condition also holds and that gives you $a > 1$

the final answer: $\{-4\} ∪ \{1, \infty\}$

Comment: I have edited OP. Sorry there was a minor mistake in the question.